Docker won't let me push to Google Cloud despite being logged in and authenticated
I have a docker image, it works locally.
I have authenticated in gcloud CLI by executing
gcloud auth application-default login

And after confirming in my browser, using the credentials helper:
gcloud auth configure-docker australia-southeast1-docker.pkg.dev

My Docker config file looks like:
{
        "credHelpers": {
                "asia.gcr.io": "gcloud",
                "australia-southeast1-docker.pkg.dev": "gcloud",
                "eu.gcr.io": "gcloud",
                "gcr.io": "gcloud",
                "marketplace.gcr.io": "gcloud",
                "staging-k8s.gcr.io": "gcloud",
                "us.gcr.io": "gcloud"
        }
}

I have double checked it's the config docker is using by running docker and verifying it's the location of the default.
I have a repository named "scaper" (without an 'r') in a project named "colesworths".

It's in this same australia-southeast1 region. I've double checked that both myself and the Google Account Services user have the right roles.

On the repository, I can see my normal user listed with the right access:

I have tagged the image as per google tutorial:
> sudo docker image ls
REPOSITORY                                                       TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED          SIZE
australia-southeast1-docker.pkg.dev/colesworths/scaper/scraper   latest    2aca96d9e3e2   58 minutes ago   1.65GB
scraper                                                          latest    2aca96d9e3e2   58 minutes ago   1.65GB
ubuntu                                                           22.04     53a843653cbc   2 weeks ago      77.9MB

But when trying to push, I get an unauthenticated error:
>sudo docker push australia-southeast1-docker.pkg.dev/colesworths/scaper/scraper:latest
The push refers to repository [australia-southeast1-docker.pkg.dev/colesworths/scaper/scraper]
36ff81bab7ad: Preparing 
8df17942bcab: Preparing 
16f00d753434: Preparing 
65bb99eee75b: Preparing 
59fbcd1fa941: Preparing 
353f35f5d7b1: Waiting 
ee97c5c0662c: Waiting 
587485d140fe: Waiting 
1b9b7346fee7: Waiting 
denied: Unauthenticated request. Unauthenticated requests do not have permission "artifactregistry.repositories.uploadArtifacts" on resource "projects/colesworths/locations/australia-southeast1/repositories/scaper" (or it may not exist)

I'm certain the resource exists (as per screenshots), and I'm fairly certain I'm logged in as per the gcloud auth pieces.
What am I missing?

Turns out the issue was because I didn't create a security group for docker. You should probably do that.
If you use sudo docker, you need to authenticate with gcloud using sudo as well.
